# How to find cell value in file names in a folder and open that file? File name contains more characters than cell value

Tags: excel, vba

This is the first week I learn vba so bear with me if I have a lot of questions;-)
So I have two folders, one folder contains the templates I need to update, the other contains the reports that the updates will be copied from. Cell A1 in each template contains the code that is specific to that BU. I need vba to find the code in the file names in the report folder and open that report. The problem is that the report names have different lengths, eg. it's named as XXX region_code_XXXXXXXXXXX, there can be any number of "X" before and after the code.

```
Sub Macro1()

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set ff = fso.getfolder("C:\Users\35264\summary\test")
For Each file In ff.Files
Workbooks.Openfile
Set wbk2 = ActiveWorkbook
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("A1").Select
rngX = Range("A1").Value
```

Now I need to find rngX in the file names in the report folder... I can't figure out how. Let me know if anyone can help! Thank you!

---

I am learning how to use dir function. I think it will be helpful to get the names of the reports first.

Comment: Would help to show specific examples of what you're working with and how each value gets mapped to the (eg) correct report

Comment: Where is this code located? In each of the templates or in a 'third' workbook?

Comment: @VBasic2008 in a third workbook

Answer (score 1):

### Combine the `FileSystemObject` Object With the `Dir` Function

- `Dir` cannot be used in nested `Do...Loops`.
- Using the FileSystemObject object, it opens files in one folder and uses the information in it to open specific files in another folder by using the Dir function. For each combination, it prints their names to the immediate window and closes each file without saving changes.
- A better way to do this would be to write the file paths of the first folder to an array by using the Dir function and then loop through the elements of the array to open each file... etc.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PrintTemplatesAndReports()
    
    ' Templates
    Const tFolderPath As String = "C:\Users\35264\summary\templates\"
    Const tWorksheetName As String = "Summary"
    Const rFilePatternAddress As String = "A1"
    Const tFileExtensionLeft As String = "xls"
    
    ' Reports
    Const rFolderPath As String = "C:\Users\35264\summary\reports\"
    Const rFileExtensionPattern As String = ".xls*"
    
    ' 1st Worbook (ThisWorkbook)
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.FolderExists(tFolderPath) Then Exit Sub
    If Not fso.FolderExists(rFolderPath) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim fsoFolder As Object: Set fsoFolder = fso.Getfolder(tFolderPath)
    
    ' Templates (using the FileSystemObject object)
    Dim fsoFile As Object
    Dim twb As Workbook, tws As Worksheet
    Dim tExtension As String, tFilePath As String
    ' Report (using Dir)
    Dim rwb As Workbook
    Dim rFilePattern As String, rFileName As String, rFilePath As String
    ' Counters
    Dim ttCount As Long, tCount As Long, rCount As Long
    
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
        ttCount = ttCount + 1
        tExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile)
        If InStr(1, tExtension, tFileExtensionLeft, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            tCount = tCount + 1
            tFilePath = tFolderPath & fsoFile.Name
            ' 2nd Workbook (Template)
            Set twb = Workbooks.Open(tFilePath)
            On Error Resume Next
                Set tws = twb.Worksheets(tWorksheetName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not tws Is Nothing Then
                rFilePattern = CStr(tws.Range(rFilePatternAddress).Value)
                rFileName = Dir(rFolderPath, "*" & rFilePattern _
                    & "*" & rFileExtensionPattern)
                Do Until Len(rFileName) = 0
                    rCount = rCount + 1
                    rFilePath = rFolderPath & rFileName
                    ' 3rd Workbook (Report)
                    Set rwb = Workbooks.Open(rFolderPath, rFileName)
                    
                    ' Do your thing, e.g.:
                    
                    Debug.Print twb.Name, rwb.Name
                    
                    
                    
                    rwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
                    rFileName = Dir ' next report
                Loop
                Set tws = Nothing
            End If
            twb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    Next fsoFile ' next template
    
    MsgBox "Template files processed: " & tCount & "(" & ttCount & ")" _
        & vbLf & "Report files processed: " & rCount & "(" & tCount & ")", _
        vbInformation
        
End Sub
```